# file organisation in windows using perl

Tags: windows, perl, file, directory

I am working on a windows machine and I have a directory filled with ~200k of files which I need to organise. This is a job I will need to do regularly with different filename sets but with similar patterns so perl seemed a good tool to use.

Each filename is made up of {a string A}{2 or 3 digit number B}{single letter "r" or "x"}{3 digit number}.extension

I want to create a folder for each string A

Within each folder I want a sub-folder for each B

I then want to move each file into its relevant sub-folder

So it will end up looking something like

```
/CustomerA/1
/CustomerA/2
/CustomerA/3
/CustomerB/1
/CustomerB/2
/CustomerB/3
```

etc with the files in each sub-folder

so CustomerA888x123.xml is moved into /CustomerA/888/

I have the list of files in an array but I am struggling with splitting the file name out to its constituent parts and using the parts effectively.

Thanks for the answer. I ended up with this:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(move);
use File::Path qw(make_path);

opendir my $dir, ".";
my @files = readdir($dir);
closedir $dir;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    my ($cust, $num) = $file =~ m/(\D+)(\d+)/;
    my $dirname = "$cust/$num";
    my @dirs_made = make_path($dirname, { verbose => 1 });
    move($file, $dirname) or warn "cant move $file to $dirname: $!";
}
```

Comment: You will have to show the program that you have tried before we can help you to fix it

Comment: I edited the code in your question to add some indentation and blank lines, for readability. If you don't like that please roll it back -- click on "_edited ..._" (above the username) and then click on "_rollback_" under the previous version.

Comment: thats great, thanks. There are blank lines and greater indentation in the code I wrote but when I was pasting it in as a comment the formatting went a bit pear shaped so I deleted blank lines thinking that was causing the formatting issues.
Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your description of file names, this regex should parse what you need

```
my ($cust, $num) = $filename =~ m/(\D+)(\d+)/;
```

Use a more precise pattern if you wish or need to be more specific about what precedes the number, for example `[a-zA-Z]` for letters only.

With that on hand, you can create directories using the core module [`File::Path`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html), for example

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);
my $dirname = "$cust/$num";
my @dirs_made = make_path($dirname, { verbose => 1 });
```

This creates the path as needed, returning the names of created directories. It also prints the names with the `verbose`. If the directory exists it quietly skips it. If there are problems it raises a [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/die.html) so you may want to wrap it in [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/eval.html)

```
eval { make_path($dirname) };
if ($@) { 
    warn "Error with make_path($dirname): $@";
}
```

Also note the [`File::Path::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Path-Tiny/lib/File/Path/Tiny.pod) module as an alternative, thanks to [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%C3%9Cn%C3%BCr) for bringing it up. Other than being far lighter, it also has the more common error-handling policy whereby a false is returned on failure so you don't need an `eval` but only the usual check

```
use File::Path::Tiny;
File::Path::Tiny::mk($path) or warn "Can't mk($path): $!";
```

The module behaves similarly to [`mkdir`](http://search.cpan.org/~cwest/ppt-0.14/bin/rmdir) in many ways, see the linked documentation.

Move the files using the `move` function form the core module [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html), for example

```
use File::Copy qw(move);
move($file, $dirname)  or warn "Can't move $file to $dirname: $!";
```

All this can be in a loop over the array with the file names.

Comment: Does `make_path` really die on failure?

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I believe so. I always `eval` it, and I tried on cmdline now.

Comment: What was the cause of failure?

Comment: @Borodin  I attempted to make path right in `/`, for which I don't have permissions (and the rest of the one-liner isn't executed).  When I `eval` it I get `mkdir  /new_dir: Permission denied`

Comment: You're right. I don't like that at all. It doesn't even appear to be documented.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, completely agree.  I learned about it by being bit.  But I don't know enough about alternatives (and it's always in a little library for me).

Comment: From the contents of `$@` it seems to be using the shell. I think I'll raise a bug report for that.

Comment: You could use [File::Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path::Tiny)

Comment: @SinanÜnür  Thank you -- that looks exactly like what the doctor ordered. I am adding it to the post, as well.

Comment: The answers were great, really appreciate the help. However I wasn't able to use FILE::PATH::TINY as it wasn't found, I guess I would have had to add the library = working on an old win7 machine with Perl5 installed